# Should this tag be [hidden] forever?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

[hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hidden) currently has 1,728 questions and I'm sure each of them can live without this ambiguous piece of a mess.

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? Is it unambiguous?**

I mean, it kinda *does* describe the content, but not fully. A title is the correct place for that, not a meaningless tag.

Oh, and talking about ambiguity, take a look at its tag wiki:

> Hidden could refer to a style value in CSS for the visibility property, a selector in jQuery, a possible value for the type attribute of an input or to an `HTML5` attribute.

This is, without a doubt, screams ***uncertain***.

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

I think so, as long as somebody is not using for this tag for questions about their new hide-and-seek game they just invented with their friends.

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

Not at all. As I mentioned, if a question is about something hidden, the title and/or the question itself should mention it.

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

More or less, yes. But we can all agree on that nobody can be a *hidden expert*.

Comment: I doubt the tag should be burned. The tag wiki could be more specific, but says it's about hiding and hidden things on websites (the jQuery selector just selects the HTML elements hidden through CSS). The actual usage, however, also includes things like hidden files in Windows, hiding things in several programs (such as hiding columns in Excel). However, such misuse is limited. In my opinion, not a great tag, but I'm not sure it's terrible enough to be burninated.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I agree to a certain. In that case, we should create separate tags for each individual case that this tag unifies currently, e.g. [tag:css-hidden], [tag:jquery-hidden].

Comment: those might be overly specific. Since the jQuery selector actually uses the css hidden attribute to select hidden elements, there might also be a lot of questions using both proposed tags. I think that proposed situation might not be better than what we currently have.

Comment: Yeah, lets keep an ambiguous tag, so that experts have to be flooded by questions they don't know the answer. Pro tip: each tag should not be ambiguous. It's the very first question on the burnination guidelines of Shog.